# В строке состояния браузера выводится искаженный URL ссылки

Tags: javascript, php, html

Сайт писал не я.

Есть страница на сайте, все страницы раздела, включая её имеют неисправность:
В ней дублируется раздел.
Например, для страницы https://teremok-nnov.ru/Stati/naruzhnaya-oblicovka-dlya-karkasnogo-doma при наведении на "Главная / Наружная облицовка для каркасного дома" происходит эта ошибка.

Тег `<base>` на этой странцие не устанавливается, `window.location` тоже не меняется.

Аргумент `title` у ссылки тоже не задан.

Может нужно ещё что-то посмотреть? Не знаю, что еще можно проверить.

Такое поведение я наблюдал в Opera и Firefox, в других браузерах не проверял.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в том, как выводится относительный URL. В его начале должен быть символ '/' (slash).